# Tweak raster calculation

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I’m creating layers with qgis 3.4 raster calculator. How can I go back and modify the  calcs or do I have to start over every time?

Answer (score 2):

The raster calculator creates a new layer. The calculations aren't stored in the new layer; only the result of the calculation is stored. To modify the calculation, you have to re-run the calculator.

The good news is that since QGIS 3, most processing algorithms stay open after you run them, with all their settings intact. So *if you don't close the raster calculator*, you can modify the expression and re-run it.

If you did close the raster calculator, you'll need to enter the expression again. If you originally ran the algorithm through the Processing Toolbox, the expression you used is saved in the Processing Toolbox History.

[image]

Suggestions:

- Use temporary layers when testing out a calculation. This is the default setting; just leave the Output as `[Save to temporary file]` instead of typing a file path and file name. Temporary layers are deleted when you close the QGIS project, so your permanent storage doesn't get cluttered with lots of extra copies of slightly different raster calculations. Once you achieve a result you want to keep, make sure to save it as a permanent layer.
- Use the plugin qNote to save your raster calculator expressions as text notes in the QGIS project file.

Comment: This answer solves my immediate problem and reveals a couple of great features of qgis that I was unaware of.

Comment: Happy to help. Did it turn out that your previous calculations were saved in the log panel? I'd like to update my answer with that information.

Comment: I looked and it wasn’t in the log messages but it was in the history if you ran it from the processing toolbox. Although it you double clicked to reload it it don’t prefill.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the History button in the processing toolbox. Very useful.